# What are the event parameters in google analytics for?

Tags: events, parameters, google-analytics

I work with statistics of the application in google analytics. I have question about events parameters:

[image]

Part of them was created automatically, other parameters are custom. I found that they can't be used in reports. Is there other meaning of these parameters except displaying information about events of 30 last minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is another meaning. Say, for instance, you want to track how many menu clicks happen on a particular nav bar by item. Well, you create an event in GTM to send that data to GA4 shown below:
[image: event tag for GA4]

Please note that the two parameters with this event will be stored for analysis in GA4 ONLY when you add them as custom dimensions. It's a pain we didn't have in universal Google Analytics but we now have to deal with this. I hope it helps answer your question.